# Use ScriptBlock as determination for Mandatory

Tags: validation, function, powershell

I was hoping that I could setup a cmdlet so that it would use an environment variable for a parameter value if it exists, or otherwise prompt.

```
function Test-Mandatory
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = { [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Env:TEST_PARAM) })]
    [string]
    $foo = $Env:TEST_PARAM
  )

  Write-Host $foo
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that regardless of whether or not I have a `$Env:TEST_PARAM` set, the cmdlet always prompts for $foo.

I could rework the validation to use `[ValidateScript({ #snip #})`, but then I wouldn't get Powershell prompting for the required value anymore, should `$Env:TEST_PARAM` not exist.  I would simply get a validation error.

So 2 questions here

- Why can I even assign a scriptblock to Mandatory if it doesn't appear to be honored?
- Is there a simple way to get the default PS prompting behavior given the criteria I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, here's what Microsoft had to say about it:

> "It’s not really a bug.  Script blocks are valid attribute arguments –
>   e.g. ValidateScriptBlock wouldn’t work very well otherwise.
>   Attribute arguments are always converted to the parameter type.  In
>   the case of Mandatory – it takes a bool, and any time you convert a
>   ScriptBlock to bool, you’ll get the value $true.  You never invoke a
>   script block to do a conversion."

Comment: A-ha.. excellent answer.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Interesting note re: conversion.

Comment: So, does that mean that `[Parameter(Mandatory={...})]` will always result in a mandatory parameter, no matter what the script block returns?

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, you can always validate the value within the script. Just set the value to the environment variable as the default value. When I tried the validation with `($foo -eq $null)` it didn't work, so I switched it to `($foo -eq "")`.  Here is a sample I tested to get what you were asking for:

```
function Test-Mandatory
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [string] $foo = $Env:TEST_PARAM
  )
begin {
    if ($foo -eq "") { 
        $foo = Read-Host "Please enter foo: "
    }
} #end begin
process {
  Write-Host $foo
} #end process
} #end function
```

As for the mandatory question, I believe if you assign a default value (even if it is empty), it will satisfy the mandatory assignment.  When it goes to check if the value is present, since it was assigned a value, the mandatory checks true, allowing it to move on.

Comment: You are correct that a default value prevents the `Mandatory` scriptblock from running.  I'll give you the 'correct' for that.

Answer (score 0):

Of note, this doesn't work as you would expect...   I would expect $foo to be marked as mandatory **only if $Env:TEST_PARAM does not exist**.

However, even when $Env:TEST_PARAM exists, the shell prompts :(

```
function Test-Mandatory
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = { [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Env:TEST_PARAM) })]
    [string]
    $foo
  )

if (!$PsBoundParameters.foo) { $foo = $Env:TEST_PARAM }

  Write-Host $foo
}
```